# Options to work with Visual Studio 2008 project targeting Windows Mobile 6 platform

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile-6, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I have an old app that was developed in Visual Studio 2008 targeting Windows Mobile 6 devices (Intermec Handhelds).  I needed to make few enhancements to the app and tried to open it in Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition but it is not supported.  I thought of installing either VS2008 or VS2008 SP1, but I was unable to find the installers on Microsoft.com.   Unfortunately, we are unable to upgrade our devices and so we are stuck with the Windows Mobile 6.

Any suggestions?  Does anyone know if it is possible to develop Windows Mobile 6 apps using VS2015?

Thanks.

Comment: Of course it's not possible. Contact Microsoft to see if they can provide you with a decade-old version of their IDE.

Comment: With an msdn subscription from Microsoft you can still download VS 2008 from their website. You have to install the SDK for Windows Mobile 6 as well
https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6135

Comment: Or you buy a used VS2008 packet.